# React dnd error 'Jest encountered an unexpected token' while running jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-dnd

Below are the version specification.

react: 18.1.0
react-dnd: 16.0.1

I am getting below error.

[image]

// jest.preset

```js
process.env.TZ = 'UTC'
const nxPreset = require('@nrwl/jest/preset')

module.exports = {
  ...nxPreset,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^antd/es/(.*)$': `${__dirname}/node_modules/antd/lib/$1`
  },
  transform: {
    '\\.svg$': `${__dirname}/tools/tests/svgrTransformer.js`,
    '\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|webp)$': `${__dirname}/tools/tests/imagerTransformer.js`
  },
  coverageReporters: [ 'lcov', 'text-summary' ],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
...
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [`${__dirname}/jest.setup.js`, 'jest-canvas-mock']
}
```

Comment: could you please, add your jest config: jest.config.js, babel.config.js (if you have one)

Comment: @FabioRibeirodeCarvalho added jest.preset.ts

Comment: try add this config and run to see what happens:     
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(react-dnd)/)']

Comment: I tried it already. Even gone through this https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/3443 for more reference, But didn't worked. Still getting same error.

Comment: Yes, the Jest when break solving some dependencies is a nightmare when crashing. One more attempt. Adapt this code to use @babel/plugin-transform-runtime in your config, I don't know if you are using ts, if not can remove the  @babel/preset-typescript:     presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
        ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }]
    ],
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']

Comment: Yes I am using TS. I tried to add '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime' this in babel.config.js (which have created just to add this). But no success. Is there anything we can do around mapping of src and dist folder under react-dnd. I have seen that src has all .ts files and dist has .js. Seems like it is pointing to wrong file.

Comment: I've tried simulate it in sandbox to try replicate the problem but I can't: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-jest-react-ts-my4mtl?file=/src/Example.tsx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250018/discussion-between-suraj-bande-and-fabio-ribeiro-de-carvalho).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation find a solution worked for me.

Below changes worked for me.

**Jest.config.ts**

```
module.exports = {
...
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!react-dnd|dnd-core|@react-dnd)'],

transform: { 
    ['(react-dnd|dnd-core|@react-dnd).+\\.[tj]sx?$'] : ['babel-jest', { presets: ['@nrwl/react/babel'] }] 
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

install `react-dnd-cjs` and `react-dnd-html5-backend-cjs` and change your setup like this:

```
{
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["@testing-library/jest-dom"],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|svg)$": "jest-transform-stub",
        "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
        "react-dnd": "react-dnd-cjs",
        "react-dnd-html5-backend": "react-dnd-html5-backend-cjs"
    },
    "setupFiles": ["./setupTests.js"]
}
```